# How to change dimension without losing quality?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-quality, dimensions

Is it possible to make a .jpeg photo smaller without losing quality ?

I have an image with 1274px in height I want to change its height to 200px without losing quality.

Because when I zoom in the image I lose the details and the quality. [image: Original image with 1274px in height]

Comment: why are you zooming in?? yes of course you can.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply.
Because I want to put the image on pdf file, so for some reason people will zoom in the image to see its details (numbers) so when it comes to zoom you can't read the details this is my problem, I want to change its height without losing the details and quality.

Comment: oooooh ok then, that wasnt clear.

Comment: also bright green on white is a readability no-no...

Comment: The question is a bit confusing because you do not in fact want to make the image smaller. You just want to make its physical dimensions smaller!

Comment: @joojaa Thanks for your reply.
I want to make the image smaller with 200px height in screen and when you zoom in you can still read the details (numbers) like it's still in its original dimension, I hope that's clear enough

Answer (score 1):

The confusion (dont worry the confusion is common) here is that your refering to pixels in two different contexts,

- as a length dimension,
- and as a raster graphix measurement.

This is not sane. Fortunately makers of PDF have a differwent world view and they call length dimensions points, inches, mm, cm or something other. Oncer you reformulate your question as:

*I want the height of my image to be 200 points*

It all makes sense now, even you can google the answer after this change.

Basically just open the image and choose Image -> Image Scale. **Uncheck** resample and type a height of 200 points,or whatever linear unit youyr using as base scale.

**Note**: A pixel has no size so scaling a pixel is meaningless.

PS: Why on earth your image is a jpg? This is a completely separate issue offcourse. thing is you have a vector drawing to beging with why make it rasterized?

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply.
I did the same as you told me " Image -> Image Scale. Uncheck resample and type a height of 200 " It doesn't work

Comment: @YounesMouaddib - Assuming you remembered to use *points* as the dimension unit (or, really, anything else that has a real-world size meaning, like *cm* or *inches*), then the image will be rescaled (its resolution will change). *It will still have the same number of pixels*, so you won't *see* a difference in Photoshop; all you have changed is its default *printing* size, which will carry over into a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you only loose quality when you UP-scale.

However when you shrink this to 200px height you will not be able to read the text...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
That's exactly my problem I can't read the text when I zoom in the image.

Answer (score 0):

if you reduce the number of pixels in your image you **will** lose quality. Think that pixels are oranges and your image is a crate; you cannot fit the same amount of oranges in a smaller crate.

However, you can minimize the quality loss by following a few steps. 
Resize your image to the correct size. Say you're going to use this image in a website, if you're going to display it at 400px height then that is the correct size for your image.

Avoid JPEG quality loss: export your image with higher quality / less compression. That can be set in the **Save for Web** options.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply.
Actually I exported the image at 200px height with higher quality but when I zoom in the image I lose the details (numbers) and quality.
I want to put the image on pdf file

Comment: if you want to add it to a PDF why does it need to be so small? Resize in the tool you're using to generate the PDF (I suppose something like Adobe Indesign) and define the resolution for the images in the PDF settings